# Ignoring invalid mail server certificates in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am attempting to send an email, although an error message returned saying:

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

My code is as follows:

```
   static void sendEmail()
        {
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress("xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx");
            const string fromPassword = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
            const string subject = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "mailserver",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", fromPassword)
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = bodyglobal
            })
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting

```
 EnableSsl = false;
```

I had this issue a few weeks ago and this was the fix. If your program doesnt need/use SSL then a smtpexecption will fire with that error message.

Comment: Hi, EnableSsl = false did not work :( Can you show an example of your second suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

Sending email depends on how the SMTP server is configured.

> According to gmail confiruged You need to remove this line of code

```
UseDefaultCredentials = false,
```

just comment this line and your message will be send.

```
 var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "mailserver",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            // do not use this command
           // UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", fromPassword)
        };
```

Microsoft suggest not to use defaultcredentials when possible. See this
[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.usedefaultcredentials%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)